# Is a letter a linguistic unit?

Tags: terminology, written-language

According to [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/linguistic%20unit) a linguistic unit is

> one of the natural units into which linguistic messages can be analyzed.

So, can a linguistic unit be a letter, a syllable, a word or a sentence?

Also, is the linguistic message something concrete, for example a text, or is it something conceptual, that is a meaning?

Comment: Maybe? You'd have to ask the author of that website, I don't think "linguistic unit" is a very consistently used term.

Comment: I suppose it is a unit of the (very atypical) subset of linguistic messages which are written messages.

Comment: Linguistic units! Oh those good olde days of structural linguistics.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Never mind. :)  not a letter but a grapheme, which is its superordinate  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme

Answer (score 3):

The concept of "unit" is not a term of linguistics, so you have to draw on an independent epistemology and not specifically linguistics to understand what a "unit" is. I understand a "unit" to be a mental abstraction, abstracted from things that it is like but distinct from. The crow on my porch is an example, one which happens to be constant regardless of label (whether or not I call it "crow", "corbeau", "kråke" or "garja"). A linguistic unit is a specific kind of unit, one that has to do with language. Syllables, words, phonemes, letters, sentences are all units which are about language, thus linguistic units.

This is congruent with the vocabulary definition you give. But linguistic units are not all "messages" – that definition commits the fallacy of "the primacy of messages". You can use language to transmit messages, just as you can use paint to convey emotions, but the elements of paint (dirt of various types, lipids, etc.) are not units that emotions can be analyzed into. A "message" is not something concrete, indeed it is so open-ended that linguists can never be sure what others mean by "message". It is sometimes seen as being "communicative intent", but that suggests that the intent is always to communicate and never to obfuscate. Indeed, a person can use linguistic units without have any awareness or "intent", when their mental capacity is suitably diminished.

Comment: Actually, linguistic unit is a valid term in linguistics, especially in the past. It is still occasionally used in research but since structural linguistics is no longer en vogue, it's become much less common.

Comment: Doesn't obfuscation (in speech) usually involve the communication of an intelligible message? An obfuscatory message isn't even necessarily an untruthful one -- rather, the key is that it doesn't fully reveal the speaker's _intent_ in saying what s/he says.

Comment: The principal problems of linguistics are segmentation and classification. Segmentation creates segments by either recognizing or inserting boundaries; classification identifies segments by type (phonological type or syntactic type or both). These were developed for oral language and work best there, but they can be applied, mutatis mutandis, to natural sign languages. Some can be applied to writing systems, but "letter" is a useful term only in some alphabetic systems. It makes no sense to talk of a Chinese "letter", for instance. Writing only represents about 25% of language; it's imprecise.

Comment: I thought the Chinese letter "q" represents a palatal. I suppose you mean that calling "其" a letter somewhat abuses the term "letter".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to remember that language can be analysed in different ways. If you are describing the sequence of sounds a speaker produces, it is adequate to classify segments of sound as phonemes and to call the characters or sequences of characters that represent each phoneme in the written language as a *letter*. In that sense, the word "light" would be composed of the letter "l" for the sound /l/, the letter "igh" for the sound /ai/, and the letter "t" for the sound /t/. The letter "igh" is composed of three characters, namely "i", "g", and "h", each of which is represented graphically with a different drawing (glyph). So, responding your question: yes, a letter is a graphological unit that corresponds to a phoneme. In that sense, a letter is a unit as long as we are analysing text in terms of phonology and graphology. It is not, however, a grammatical unit of any kind. The smallest grammatical unit is the morpheme.

Comment: What sense of "grammar" are you using? Features (sub-parts of phonemes) are in grammar so they are grammatical. If grammar is about syntax only, and there is a morphological component, then either the word, the syntactic feature, or the pre-terminal category is the smallest unit (depending on which of those things you think exist). The morpheme is the minimum unit of the lexicon (i.e. it is w.r.t. the lexicon a primitive).

Answer (score -1):

A unit of voice is an 'allophone' (a sound distinct from other allophones).  A unit of linguistics is a 'phoneme' (a signal to the muscles, distinct from other phonemes).  Written language evolved to convey the spoken language without sound, but that does not require that the two are correlated (look at Chinese).  Languages like English do have correlation between letters and phonemes, but it is not one-to-one (especially for vowels).  Because we have things like silent 'e' that affect other vowel groups, it is hard to imagine 'units' unless you paraphrase each syllable into a consonantal onset and a vowel [+ consonant] rime. (ex: site = 's'+'i_e'+'t')